# LocationListener doesnt listen for gps when it is disabled. Any idea what am i doing wrong?

Tags: android, gps, location

I am trying to pop up a window message when the gps is disabled but location listener doesn't respond when I enable or disable. I don't understand what am I doing wrong. Anyone could give me a hand on this? Thanks in advance!

This is  my code where I am using locationlistener:

```
public class MapsActivityy extends AppCompatActivity {

    private LocationManager locationManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        //locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        // Initialize location manager.
        locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        // Check if user has granted permissions.
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // We do not have permissions.
            return;
        }

        // Check if we did find a location provider.
        if (locationManager == null) {
            // No gps provider was found. Inform user.
            return;
        }
        // Initialize location manager and register location listener.
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                2000,
                10, locationListenerGPS);


        if (!locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
            openGpsWindow();
        }else{
            updateLocationUI();
        }



    }




    //Location listener that listens for location state changes.
    LocationListener locationListenerGPS = new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(android.location.Location location) {
            // Called when the location has changed.
                    }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
            // Called when the provider status changes.
                    }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
                    }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            // Called when the provider is disabled by the user.
            openGpsWindow();
        }
    };

    //Pops up a window in order to open GPS
    public void openGpsWindow() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, EnableGpsWindow.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

I am trying to pop up a window message when the gps is disabled but location listener doesn't respond when I enable or disable. I don't understand what am I doing wrong. Anyone could give me a hand on this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use broadcast receiver to get gps enabled or disabled events and then broadcast that event inside your application using internal broadcast receiver.

This is your broadcast recevier which will listen for gps events.

```
public class LocationStateChangeBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver 
{

public static final String GPS_CHANGE_ACTION = "com.android.broadcast_listeners.LocationChangeReceiver";

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {


    if (intent.getAction() != null && intent.getAction().equals(context.getString(R.string.location_change_receiver))) {
        if (!isGpsEnabled(context)) {
            sendInternalBroadcast(context, "Gps Disabled");
        }
    }
}

private void sendInternalBroadcast(Context context, String status) {
    try {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.putExtra("Gps_state", status);
        intent.setAction(GPS_CHANGE_ACTION);
        context.sendBroadcast(intent);

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static boolean isGpsEnabled(Context context) {
    LocationManager manager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    return manager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
}
}
```

Create Internal broadcast receiver class to receive events.

```
class InternalLocationChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

//        this method will be called on gps disabled
//        call openGpsWindow  here
    }
}
```

Now copy this code in your activity to register broadcast receivers.

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

InternalLocationChangeReceiver internalLocationChangeReceiver = new
        InternalLocationChangeReceiver();

LocationStateChangeBroadcastReceiver locationStateChangeBroadcastReceiver = new LocationStateChangeBroadcastReceiver();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    try {
        registerReceiver(locationStateChangeBroadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter("android.location.PROVIDERS_CHANGED"));

        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
        intentFilter.addAction(LocationStateChangeBroadcastReceiver.GPS_CHANGE_ACTION);
        registerReceiver(internalLocationChangeReceiver, intentFilter);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    unregisterReceiver(locationStateChangeBroadcastReceiver);
    unregisterReceiver(internalLocationChangeReceiver);
}
}
```

Comment: but I need to extend AppCompatActivity as well, how could I use broadcast receiver?

Comment: Pardon, due to improper fomating you are unable to see class name in code block. Create a new class named LocationStateChangeBroadcastReceiver , this class will extend BroadcastReceiver not your activity. I have edited the answer with proper indentation.

Comment: what you sent me is if gps is enabled right? I want is gps is disabled to open my function openGpsWindow how is this gonna happen?

Comment: I understood this but  where am I gonna call my function openGpsWindow ()?

Comment: Inside onReceive method of InternalLocationChangeReceiver.

Comment: I disable the gps and still I got no window :(

Comment: what is this string: (R.string.location_change_receiver) ?

Comment: android.location.PROVIDERS_CHANGED

Comment: i followed all steps why i don't get my function openGpsWindow when i disable gps? :(

Comment: have a look at my code pls and check, i am doing your steps
https://pastebin.com/zYvxXnEV

Comment: We forgot to register actual location provider broadcast in activity's onCreate. I have updated the answer and checked it is working fine now.

Comment: i don't know why but it still doesn't work, can you please adjust the correct code into mine : https://pastebin.com/zYvxXnEV ? Please i have been trying to fix this for so long and we are so close! I will appreciate it!!

Comment: even though i register the receiver the debbuger says that i didn't register

Comment: I have pasted the activity code and updated the answer, the code is working perfectly, recheck your code inside LocationStateChangeBroadcastReceiver  class.

Comment: it works thanks so much, it can understand if gps is enabled/disabled but now I got another problem, after enabling again the gps I got again window to open gps even though it is on, have you got any idea what to do?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188007/discussion-between-nik-and-roshaan-farrukh).

Answer (score 0):

[Don't use the gps provider , Kindly use the Fused location services , i have shared a code of using it already and mention the code to check the location request, just tap on link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54551020/4754710)

```
 var locationRequest = LocationRequest()
        locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
        locationRequest.setInterval(5000)
        locationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000)
        locationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(2f)
// Create LocationSettingsRequest object using location request
        val builder = LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
        builder.addLocationRequest(locationRequest)
        val locationSettingsRequest = builder.build()

        // Check whether location settings are satisfied
        // https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/SettingsClient
        val settingsClient = LocationServices.getSettingsClient(this)
        settingsClient.checkLocationSettings(locationSettingsRequest)
                .addOnFailureListener {

                    AppUtils.showToast(this,getString(R.string.enable_high_accuracy_mode),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).hashCode()
                    val callGPSSettingIntent = Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS)
                   this@BusDriverDashboardActivity.startActivityForResult(callGPSSettingIntent,1)
                }.addOnSuccessListener { }
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/54551020/4754710

Comment: your code got me confused I didn't quite understand, I am not that familiar. But gps provider why isn't working?

Comment: Google Upgraded the Providers to Fused client.